# Is it possible to find a $n\times n$ matrix $M$ such that $M^2 =- I_n$, where $-I_n$ is the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to find a $n\times n$ matrix $M$ such that $M^2 = -I_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix?

For odd $n$, this cannot hold, since $(-1)^n = \det(-I_n) = \det (M^2) = \det(M)^2$ but what can one say about even $n$?

Comment: I think you're looking for $M^2=-I_n$, right?

Comment: For the case where $n$ is even, you can start by solving the case for $n=2$. By Block matrix multiplication, it's not difficult to find an example in generals cases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut yeah right.

Comment: Take any $\mathbb{R}$-basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$, and then consider what multiplication by $i$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ does to the basis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the $2 \times 2$ matrix

$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 1$

we have

$J^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = -I_2, \tag 2$

as may be readily verified by an easy calculation.  We may then construct a $2n \times 2n$ matrix $M_0$ by placing $n$ copies of $J$ along the (block) diagonal:

$M_0 = \begin{bmatrix} J & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & J & \ldots & 0 \\ \dots & \vdots & J & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & J\end{bmatrix}; \tag 3$

it is equally easy to see that

$M_0^2 = -I_{2n}; \tag 4$

this establishes the existence of a desired $2n \times 2n$ matrix. An entire family of such matrices may be had by taking matrices $M$ similar to $M_0$:

$M = SM_0S^{-1}; \tag 5$

then

$M^2 = SM_0S^{-1} SM_0S^{-1} = SM_0 M_0S^{-1} = S(-I_{2n}) S^{-1} = -I_{2n}. \tag 6$

We see there are many matrices of the requisite form.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

A classical example is
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$

This is a classical example as it allows to mimic (or represent) complex number computations using real arithmetic. 
$$
z=a+ib \leftrightarrow a\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right) + b\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & -b \\ b & a\end{array}\right)
$$